# Camera 2 api showing BufferQueue has been abandoned

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-camera2, bufferqueue

I am using camera 2 api in my application by following the google [sample link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker)

For the first time it is working properly. If you go back and come again many times, then the app is getting crashed saying -

> [CAM_ID(0)][PREVIEW_BUF]-ERR(m_bufferCollectorThreadFunc[3196]):dequeueBuffer
>   failed, dequeue(5), collected(5) 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208 3250-4904/?
>   E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView -
>   com.example/com.example.FaceTrackerActivityPayment@7edb372@0#0]
>   dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208
>   3405-15497/? E/ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer
>   failed 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208 3250-4904/? E/BufferQueueProducer:
>   [SurfaceView -
>   com.example/com.example.FaceTrackerActivityPayment@7edb372@0#0]
>   dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208
>   3405-15497/? E/ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer
>   failed 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208 3250-4904/? E/BufferQueueProducer:
>   [SurfaceView -
>   com.example/com.example.FaceTrackerActivityPayment@7edb372@0#0]
>   dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208
>   3405-15497/? E/ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer
>   failed 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208 3250-4904/? E/BufferQueueProducer:
>   [SurfaceView -
>   com.example/com.example.FaceTrackerActivityPayment@7edb372@0#0]
>   dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned 2019-09-20 17:33:12.208
>   3405-15497/? E/ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer
>   failed 2019-09-20 17:33:12.209 3250-4904/? E/BufferQueueProducer:
>   [SurfaceView -
>   com.example/com.example.FaceTrackerActivityPayment@7edb372@0#0]
>   dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned 2019-09-20 17:33:12.209
>   3405-15497/? E/ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer
>   failed 2019-09-20 17:33:12.209 3405-15497/?
>   E/ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: @@@@ERR(alloc):*bufHandle == NULL
>   failed 2019-09-20 17:33:12.209 3405-15497/?
>   E/ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(dequeueBuffer):alloc failed